# send jquery post request and process data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, request

trying to send post request to php file witch resievs feed url from my request parses it and sends back as JSON... so want to get the json it sends and put it into htlm new to js cant make it work.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$(".feed").on("click", function() {
    var feedurl = $(this).attr("value");
    $.post("syndicate.php", {value : feedurl},function(){});
    load();


    });
    function load(){
 $.getJSON("syndicate.php",function(result){

    console.log(result);
    var items = result.items;
    for (var i=0; i<items.length;i++){
        var s = "<table class='dataTable'";
        s += "<tr><td>title</td><td>" + items[i].title + "</td></tr>";
        s += "<tr><td>link</td><td><a href='" + items[i].url + "'>open     link</a></td></tr>";
        s += "<tr><td>content</td><td>" + items[i].content + "</td></tr>";
        s += "</table>";
        $("#widget-content").append(s);
    }

});
}
```

Comment: i realize that need to process the reseived json in post request callback but getting syntax errors cant make it work: )

Comment: Can you give us an example result of syndicate.php? And which errors are thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".feed").on("click", function() {
    var feedurl = $(this).attr("value");
    var response = $.get("../syndicate.php", {
        value : feedurl
    }, function() {
    });

    response.done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
        var items = json.items;
```

solved!
problem was that i wasnt procesing data in same request, i was sending 2 saparate requests 1 for sending data to php and 2 to process respond.